# Access to customer's org

Tags: support, grant-login-access

What does the appexchange vendor have to do so that they can get access to customer's org as shown in the picture below?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The [ISVforce Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_intro.htm) is the best place to find details about the ongoing management of your app in subscriber orgs. You can use the [License Management App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/lma_intro.htm) and the Support Console to access your customers' orgs.

See the topic of [ISV Guide: Supporting Your Customers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_user_support.htm) for details about the LMA and how the customer grants you access to their org.

Comment: You might also mention https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/lma_requesting_login_access.htm which also states reasons why the access might not appear.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008uUgIAI think you have to have license managing application installed in your LMO, out of your package organisation, which should give you access to the clients.

"Package Support Access" gets good google hits. There are limitations I think such as it won't work for Beta applications and you can only tie it to a single App in your environment.